# pyqt5 - How to put multiple UI classes to one UI together

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

imagine i have a window with a lot of widgets and i dont want to have one big class, but several small classes. 
How can i write in in a main.py that content of both classes should show up in one window window side by side?
I dont want multiple windows in one window.
I only want all widgets together in one window
I am creating my classes with the QTDesigner.

Example:
person.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'person.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(467, 300)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 51, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 40, 71, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 51, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 80, 71, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 10, 71, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 51, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "First name"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Last name"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Salutation"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

address.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'address.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(467, 300)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 20, 51, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 90, 71, 20))
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 50, 71, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 20, 71, 20))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 90, 71, 16))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 50, 71, 20))
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Street"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "House number"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Form", "Post Code"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have hard-coded the left and right-shift of the labels and line edits in the two UIs, could create a new python file (`main.py`, say), import `person.py` and `address.py` in the new file, create a `QWidget` and apply `person.Ui_Form().setupUi` and `address.Ui_Form().setupUi` on the same widget in this particular case. This would mean that `main.py` would look something like

```
import from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import person, address

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()

    person_ui = person.Ui_Form()
    address_ui = address.Ui_Form()

    person_ui.setupUi(widget)
    address_ui.setupUi(widget)

    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Result:**

[image: screen shot]

**Edit:** At the request of OP I've added a different approach using layouts. As I mentioned in a comment, you could use form layouts to layout the labels and line edits in the person and address widgets. For this, open the layouts for the person and address widgets in Qt Designer, right-click in the Form object in the Object Inspector and choose Lay out > Lay out in a Form Layout from the context menu. Save and export the layouts as usual.

Then in the main .py file, you would need to create separate widgets for the person,  the address, and the main widget, set a `QHBoxLayout` as the layout manager for the main widget and add the person and address widgets to this layout. You could do all this in the same way as before, but if you want to add extra functionality to your main widget you could also consider sub-classing `QWidget` and using that to setup the main widget, e.g.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # setup person widget
        self.person_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.person_ui = uic.loadUi('person.ui', self.person_widget)

        # setup address widget
        self.address_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.address_ui = uic.loadUi('address.ui', self.address_widget)

        # setup main layout
        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.person_widget)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.address_widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = MainWidget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

**Result:**

[image: screenshot alternative solution]

Comment: Do you now a solution where i have not to hard code the widgets?

Comment: The most common way is to use layout managers like `QVBoxLayout` etc. to layout the widgets. They have the advantage that the size and position of the widgets is automatically updated when the window is resized. In your example I would use a `QFormLayout` to layout for each of the person and the address widgets to layout the line edits and add the two widgets to a `QHBoxLayout`.

Comment: I've added an alternative solution